# and and bitand in situations where & and && mean ref

Tags: c++, reference, language-lawyer, logical-operators

Consider the following code.
To me, the use of `and` and `bitand` is clearly a violation of semantics.

```
#include <iostream>
class C
{
    public:
    void f() and // meaning &&
    {
        std::cout << " f() and\n";
    }

    void f() bitand // meaning &
    {
        std::cout << " f() bitand\n";
    }
};
int main()
{
    C{}.f();
    C c;
    c.f();
}
```

[Find it on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/vWPPdWWWv).

Was this an oversight in the C++ specification or is it a bug in the compilers?

Comment: They are [alternative tokens](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_alternative). During parsing (or perhaps even lexing) they are replaced by `&&`, `&`, etc, which means they behave _exactly_ the same as their counterparts. You can even write `struct X{ compl X() {} };` to define a destructor. They could also be implemented as macros by the implementation.

Comment: @chrysante OMG! That's horrible, IMO.

Comment: @ThomasWeller :-) It becomes even more fun when throwing in trigraphs (that were removed in C++17 I think.). `??- X() {}` for a destructor...

Comment: @ThomasWeller I guess it doesn't really hurt anyone and I think the alternative tokens were first introduced to enable people to write C on ancient keyboards which didn't have 'special' symbols.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Was this an oversight in the C++ specification or is it a bug in the compilers?

The wording in the standard suggests that it's neither:

From the [C++11 draft](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf)

> 2.6 Alternative tokens [lex.digraph]
>
> 1. Alternative token representations are provided for some operators and punctuators.
> 2. In all respects of the language, each alternative token behaves the same, respectively, as its primary token,
>    except for its spelling.

Note: *In **all** respects of the language.*

CppReference has some information on the history when you look up [alternative operator representations](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_alternative):

> [...] source code may be written in any non-ASCII 7-bit character set [...] outside of the ISO 646 codeset

It refers to ISO 646:1983, where 1983 is the year of the standard. So these alternatives were introduced for systems and ancient keyboards which didn't have the special characters.

Comment: Not just keyboards, but entire _systems_, lacked these characters.  Less of a problem in modern times, of course.

Comment: @ThomasWeller I'm absolutely fine with the edit! Thanks!